# Binding Source of DataSet

Tags: vb.net, data-binding

I have two tables of data in one DataSet.  The Two tables fill two different DataGridViews.  Is there a way to bind these do tables together so that when DataGridView1 changes its row that the corresponding table data appears in DataGridView2 (Parent/Child).  I have looked on the web but haven't found anything yet.  I am unable to create a BindingSource due to always getting and error so I am doing everything in code. Thanks for any help.

Here is the error I'm getting: In VB.Net when I try to create a data Source I keep getting for following error "Could not load file or Assembly 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version=3.0.0.0'). I have used NuGet and installed the latest Verion (5.0.0.0) and it appears to be reference, but I still get the same error.

Here is my current code:

```
        Dim SQL1 As String = "Select * From Table1"
        Dim SQL2 As String = "Select * from Table2"
        Dim ConnString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=HeatsListDB.accdb"
        Dim OleDBConn1 As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(ConnString)
        Dim DS1 As New DataSet
        Dim DA1 As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(SQL1, OleDBConn1)
        Dim DA2 As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(SQL2, OleDBConn1)
        OleDBConn1.Open()
        DA1.Fill(DS1, "Table1")
        DA2.Fill(DS1, "Table2")
        Dim Relation As New DataRelation("Relation1", DS1.Tables("Table1").Columns("Field1"), 
        DS1.Tables("Table2").Columns("Field1"))
        DS1.Relations.Add(Relation)
        
        Me.dg1.DataSource = DS1.Tables("Table1")
        Me.dg2.DataSource = DS1.Tables("Table2")
```

Comment: Helps if you showed what you tried.  `always getting and error`  Always tell us the error, too.

Comment: [DataRelation Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarelation)

Comment: The error: In VB.Net when I try to create a data Source I keep getting for following error "Could not load file or Assembly 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version=3.0.0.0').

I have used NuGet and installed the latest Verion (5.0.0.0) and it appears to be reference, but I still get the same error. I am at a loss. I can't find a reference to version 3.0.0.0 anyplace.

Comment: I have given up on correcting this error and just do everything by code.

Comment: Here is the code I am using:

Comment: Dim SQL1 As String = "Select * From Table1"
Dim SQL2 As String = "Select * from Table2"
Dim ConnString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=HeatsListDB.accdb"
Dim OleDBConn1 As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(ConnString)
Dim DS1 As New DataSet
Dim DA1 As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(SQL1, OleDBConn1)
Dim DA2 As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(SQL2, OleDBConn1)
OleDBConn1.Open()

Comment: DA1.Fill(DS1, "Table1")
DA2.Fill(DS1, "Table2")
Dim Relation As New DataRelation("Relation1", DS1.Tables("Table1").Columns("Field1"), DS1.Tables("Table2").Columns("Field1"))
DS1.Relations.Add(Relation)

Me.dg1.DataSource = DS1.Tables("Table1")
Me.dg2.DataSource = DS1.Tables("Table2")

Comment: I hope you can make sense of this.

Comment: If you need more just ask.  I currently just use the OnClick and reset the DS for DG2.  It works fast.  There are only about 240 records in table2 and I don't expect there to be much more than that in the future.

Comment: No one should need to read the comments to understand the question and it should be obvious that reading wads of unformatted code in comments is not acceptable. Edit your question and provide ALL the relevant information there, as you should have in the first place. Format everything appropriately for easy reading. If you want to let people in the comments know that you have updated the question, add a comment that says that specifically. Please spend some time in the Help Center to learn how to ask a question properly.

Comment: [Here](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?518065) is an example I created just over 15 years ago that does what you want. The key is to configure the `DataSet` with the appropriate `DataRelation` and then bind the data via that relation. I suggest that you start with a new project to test that example, to determine whether the issue you're having with `BindingSources` is a system thing or something you're doing. Either way, if you can't work it out, you should post a new question specifically about that, then come back to this one when that's resolved.

Comment: If the above doesn't work for some reason then, as I said earlier, update your question with ALL the relevant information. Show us the actual code you're executing, formatted appropriately, and tell what happened and where it happened.

Comment: I am new at this (including code) Sorry for the problems.  I have edited my question to include the code.